# Number of deployed portlets - influence on performance

Tags: performance, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

There is wonder question: how does number of deployed portlets affect on performance of Liferay?

If I have deployed 50 war projects (summary about 80 portlets), can it be cause of very slow performance?

Or will it only insignificantly affect on performance of Liferay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Number of deployed projects, extracted in tomcat/webapps, will affect dramatically your server startup time for sure.

Depending on the portlet scope and tasks they might add an overhead to your browsing performance, but I don't think it's a big deal as long as you don't have lots of them rendering in the same page.

Now, things are a lot harder in a development machine (the tomcat server is controlled by Eclipse and you have portlets auto-deploying in that server each time you compile or change them). A portlet's  auto deployment can cause all the other webapps to deploy too. Also, in development mode, you might experience  permGen errors quite regularly, and in this case, since you're gonna have to restart the server each time, the huge startup time can become a major pain.

If you're in a development environment , you should really consider removing the webapps that are not beeing tested or needed.